# Spinless particle in external and constant magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, supersymmetry, klein-gordon-equation

I'm trying to reproduce some calculations of a paper that consist in find the energy spectrum of a spin-less particle in a external and constant magnetic field, $B$, pointed in $z$ direction. I have applied the Klein-Gordon equation with minimal coupling, and I'm in the the following situation making some reparametrization of variables:
$$\left[ \dfrac{d^2}{d\xi^2} -\dfrac{\xi^2}{(eB)^2} + \dfrac{(E^2 - k_z^2-m^2)}{(eB)^2} \right]\phi(\xi)=0$$

and the final results that I'm trying to reproduce is:
$$E_n^2=k_z^2+(2n+1)eB+m^2$$

can someone help me with a tip?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question that you are trying to ask is about finding the energy of a scalar particle in a constant background magnetic field. I am not following your procedure of solving the Klein-Gordon equation to obtain the energy spectrum. Your approach is valid under 2 conditions

(1)If the background is not affected due to the presence of an external magnetic field

(2)If you have considered a particular geometry (say cylindrical geometry) to solve your equation. This will have different solutions and you may have to consider rotation for it.

My approach is that we are still in flat space. The ordinary vacuum has been distorted by the external magnetic field. I want to find the Green's function of this theory which will provide me the energy spectrum of the theory. There exists one such formalism known as Schwinger's proper time formalism or Fock-Schwinger formalism which allows us to calculate energy in background dependent vacuum. Let us consider the vacuum to be
$$\big|\Omega \big>$$ which is background dependent vacuum. Lagrangian of a scalar field in external magnetic field is given by
$$\mathcal{L} = D^{\mu}\phi D_{\mu}^*\phi - m^2\phi\phi^*$$
where $D^{\mu} = \partial^{\mu} - ie(A^{\mu} + A^{\mu}_{ext}) = \partial^{\mu} - ie\widetilde{A}^{\mu}$
The KG equation to solve for deriving the Greens function is given by
$$\Big[D^{\mu}D_{\mu}^* + m^2\Big]\big<\Omega|G(x-x')|\Omega\big> = \delta^{(4)}(x-x')$$
On solving this equation using Schwinger's proper time formalism one obtains the propagator in momentum space as
$$D_B(k) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^le^{-k_{\perp}^2/eB}L_l(2k_{\perp}^2/eB)}{k_0^2 - (2l+1)eB -k_z^2 - m^2 + i\epsilon}$$
where $L_l(x)$ is the Laguerre polynomial. From this propagator you can see that your required energy spectrum is obtained. You can look at a few references

1. [Tzuu-Kang-Chyi](https://%09arXiv:hep-th/9912134)
2. [Schwinger](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07890)
3. [Iablokov](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07890)